# Mirror segments down in Greenplum

Tags: greenplum

I am learning Greenplum and have setup a small cluster for testing (one master, three segment hosts).

I initialized the cluster without mirroring, and have later enabled it by using gpaddmirrors. However, all of the mirrors appear as Down in gpstate and running gp_primarymirror command on the segment hosts simply hangs (that is the command that gprecoverseg runs)

```
gpadmin   2695     1  0 06:21 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/greenplum-db-4.3.8.1/bin/postgres -D /data/primary/gpseg2 -p 40002 -b 4 -z 9 --silent-mode=true -i -M quiescent -C 2

gpadmin   2698  2695  0 06:21 ?        00:00:00 postgres: port 40002, logger process    

gpadmin   2706  2695  0 06:21 ?        00:00:00 postgres: port 40002, primary process   

gpadmin   2709  2706  0 06:21 ?        00:00:00 postgres: port 40002, primary recovery process   

gpadmin   2719  2695  0 06:21 ?        00:00:00 postgres: port 40002, stats collector process    

gpadmin   2720  2695  0 06:21 ?        00:00:00 postgres: port 40002, writer process    

gpadmin   2721  2695  0 06:21 ?        00:00:00 postgres: port 40002, checkpoint process    

gpadmin   2722  2695  0 06:21 ?        00:00:00 postgres: port 40002, sweeper process    

gpadmin   2901  2207  0 06:29 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 40002

gpadmin@gpseg02:~> gp_primarymirror -h gpseg02 -p 40002
```

The last command just hangs and never finishes.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Update #1:

gprecoverseg -v output (without -v it just prints "Unable to connect to database"):

```
20160502:06:24:28:023062 gprecoverseg:gpmaster02:gpadmin-[DEBUG]:-[worker8] finished cmd: Get segment status cmdStr='ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' gpseg03 ". /usr/local/greenplum-db/./greenplum_path.sh; $GPHOME/bin/gp_primarymirror -h gpseg03 -p 40002"'  had result: cmd had rc=1 completed=True halted=False
  stdout=''
  stderr='Welcome to SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12.
mode: PrimarySegment
segmentState: ChangeTrackingDisabled
dataState: InChangeTracking
faultType: NotInitialized
mode: PrimarySegment
segmentState: ChangeTrackingDisabled
dataState: InChangeTracking
faultType: NotInitialized
```

gp_segment_configuration output:

```
testdb=# select * from gp_segment_configuration;
 dbid | content | role | preferred_role | mode | status | port  |          hostname          |          address           | replication_port | san_mounts
------+---------+------+----------------+------+--------+-------+----------------------------+----------------------------+------------------+------------
    1 |      -1 | p    | p              | s    | u      |  5432 | gpmaster02                 | gpmaster02                 |                  |
    2 |       0 | p    | p              | c    | u      | 40000 | gpseg02                    | gpseg02                    |            43000 |
   11 |       0 | m    | m              | r    | d      | 41000 | gpseg03                    | gpseg03                    |            42000 |
    3 |       1 | p    | p              | c    | u      | 40001 | gpseg02                    | gpseg02                    |            43001 |
   12 |       1 | m    | m              | r    | d      | 41001 | gpseg03                    | gpseg03                    |            42001 |
    4 |       2 | p    | p              | c    | u      | 40002 | gpseg02                    | gpseg02                    |            43002 |
   13 |       2 | m    | m              | r    | d      | 41002 | gpseg03                    | gpseg03                    |            42002 |
    5 |       3 | p    | p              | c    | u      | 40000 | gpseg04                    | gpseg04                    |            43000 |
   17 |       3 | m    | m              | r    | d      | 41000 | gpseg02                    | gpseg02                    |            42000 |
    6 |       4 | p    | p              | c    | u      | 40001 | gpseg04                    | gpseg04                    |            43001 |
   18 |       4 | m    | m              | r    | d      | 41001 | gpseg02                    | gpseg02                    |            42001 |
    7 |       5 | p    | p              | c    | u      | 40002 | gpseg04                    | gpseg04                    |            43002 |
   19 |       5 | m    | m              | r    | d      | 41002 | gpseg02                    | gpseg02                    |            42002 |
    8 |       6 | p    | p              | c    | u      | 40000 | gpseg03                    | gpseg03                    |            43000 |
   14 |       6 | m    | m              | r    | d      | 41000 | gpseg04                    | gpseg04                    |            42000 |
    9 |       7 | p    | p              | c    | u      | 40001 | gpseg03                    | gpseg03                    |            43001 |
   15 |       7 | m    | m              | r    | d      | 41001 | gpseg04                    | gpseg04                    |            42001 |
   10 |       8 | p    | p              | c    | u      | 40002 | gpseg03                    | gpseg03                    |            43002 |
   16 |       8 | m    | m              | r    | d      | 41002 | gpseg04                    | gpseg04                    |            42002 |
```

Comment: what can you see in `select * from gp_segment_configuration`? Did you try `gprecoverseg`?

Comment: I updated my original post with the output

Comment: Your mirrors are down which is a bit odd.  Can you bounce the database?  Do you have iptables enabled and blocking ports 4100x?

Comment: I tried stopping and starting it, to no avail.
iptables is not blocking these ports either (telnet from master to the segment hosts works).
You are right that it is only the mirrors which are down - the DB itself is up and functioning... :\

Answer (score 3):

This usually means there is a problem with the changetracking logs.

- "segmentState: ChangeTrackingDisabled"

Try the following:

1. Stop the database.
2. For segment "-h gpseg03 -p 40002", go in to it's datadir and delete the contents of "pg_changetracking" dir.
3. Start the database.
4. Run "gprecoverseg -F".

There could be other segments with corrupted changetracking logs. If the above steps don't work then stop the database and delete pg_changetracking for ALL segments.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue in past, i tried with gprecoverseg full after login into db in admin only mode and it works
please try this step